# Show error icon automatically in UITextField when validation is failed in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want error icon image will be shown automatically within UITextField when one of validation is failed in swift.

**Here is normal stage**
[image]

**Here is error stage when validation is failed**
[image]

For that UITextField, I've created custom UITextField as follow

```
class OvalTextField: UITextField {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        createBorder()
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createBorder()
    }

    func createBorder(){

        let errorImg = UIImageView (frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
        errorImg.image = UIImage(named: "error")
        errorImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Left

        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.93, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0).CGColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let gapLabel = UIView (frame: CGRectMake(60, 0, 10, 40))
        self.leftView = gapLabel
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

        /* Display that one when validation is failed */
        self.rightView = errorImg;
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    }
}
```

and used that UITextField in ViewController,

```
@IBOutlet var txtEmail: OvalTextField!
```

if that txtEmail is empty or not valid email address, I want to show error icon message.

Please suggest me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on when you want to perform the validation; You could use the text field delegate to update it as people type or you could perform validation when they save/submit the form

Comment: Can I ask what `clearButtonMode` setting would work here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the UITextFiledDelegate method **func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool** to valid the email when user input.

1. First set the delegate, txtEmail.delegate = self, then
2. Implement the delegate method

   ```
   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange  range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       let email = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

       if /* email is validate */ {
           textField.rightView?.hidden = false
       } else {
           textField.rightView?.hidden = true
       }

       return true
   ```

   }

Answer (score 3):

```
func validated() -> Bool {
    var valid: Bool = true
    if ((txt_EmailID.text?.isEmpty) != nil){
        // change placeholder color to red color for textfield email-id
        txt_EmailID.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Please enter Your Email ID", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
        valid = false
    }
    if ((txt_UserName.text?.isEmpty) != nil){
        // change placeholder color to red for textfield username
        txt_UserName.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Please enter User Name",attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
        valid = false
    }
    if ((txt_Password.text?.isEmpty) != nil){
        // change placeholder color to red for textfield password
        txt_Password.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Please enter Password",attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()])
        valid = false
    }
    if ((txt_MobileNo.text?.isEmpty) != nil){
        // change placeholder color to red for textfield mobile no.
        txt_MobileNo.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Please enter Mobile no.",attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
        valid = false
    }
    return valid
}
```